# How to get a RSSI of bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I am trying to get the RSSI of the bluetooth connection. First i thought to display the RSSI of all nearby devices, so i checked the internet - got some information of the bluetooth classes and checked some examples. I tried a lot of thing, but with no success. I am at stage that I cant understand where exactly is the problem.

The target SDK is 29 and min SDK is 19. I am testing it on Android 10 (SDK 29)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.BlendMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

BluetoothAdapter BA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BA.startDiscovery();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                TextView rssi_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                rssi_msg.setText(rssi_msg.getText() + "" + rssi + "dBm\n");
            }
        }
    };

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a "work around answer" but still can't do it properly. So the things that helped me and now it is working are: I made the **targetSdkVersion** to **26** (it was 29 before), **minSdkVersion** is still **19** (like before) and **compileSdkVersion** is still **29** (like before). This was in the gradle. And after I changed the target SDK I added this in my *onCreate()* method on the *MainActivity*

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)this, new String[]{
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 10);
    }
```

and now it is working on android 10, but I still can't do it for target SDK 29